# BeautifulSoup returning 403 error for some sites

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, http-status-code-403

I don't understand why I am getting a 403 error for some of these sites.

If I visit the URLs manually the pages load fine. There isn't any error message other that the 403 response, so I don't know how to diagnose the problem.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests    

test_sites = [
 'http://fashiontoast.com/',
 'http://becauseimaddicted.net/',
 'http://www.lefashion.com/',
 'http://www.seaofshoes.com/',
 ]

for site in test_sites:
    print(site)
    #get page soure
    response = requests.get(site)
    print(response)
    #print(response.text)
```

Result of running the above code is...

```
http://fashiontoast.com/

Response [403]

http://becauseimaddicted.net/

Response [403]

http://www.lefashion.com/

Response [200]

http://www.seaofshoes.com/

Response [200]
```

---

Can anyone help me understand the cause of the problem and the solution please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes page rejects GET requests that do not identify a User-Agent.

Visit the page with a browser (Chrome). Right clcik then 'Inspect'. Copy the User-Agent header of the GET request (look in the Network tab.

[image]

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

with requests.Session() as se:
    se.headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Language": "en"
    }


test_sites = [
 'http://fashiontoast.com/',
 'http://becauseimaddicted.net/',
 'http://www.lefashion.com/',
 'http://www.seaofshoes.com/',
 ]

for site in test_sites:
    print(site)
    #get page soure
    response = se.get(site)
    print(response)
    #print(response.text)
```

**Output:**

```
http://fashiontoast.com/
<Response [200]>
http://becauseimaddicted.net/
<Response [200]>
http://www.lefashion.com/
<Response [200]>
http://www.seaofshoes.com/
<Response [200]>
```

Comment: Great answer. Thank you. It really helped me understand the underlying problem and how to help myself in future. :-)